# Error when installing Electrum

Tags: apt

I am trying to install bitcoin wallet electrum 3.1.2 on whonix. It has always been easy before just follow instuctions on electrum.org. Like this

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pyqt5 python3-pip
```

Install Electrum:

```
sudo pip3 install https://download.electrum.org/3.1.2/Electrum-3.1.2.tar.gz
```

Install dependencies works without problem but when i try to install Electrum i get this error messege:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2595, in _dep_map
    return self.__dep_map
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2457, in __getattr__
  raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1266, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.extras):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2401, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2597, in _dep_map
    self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2630, in _compute_dependencies
    common = frozenset(reqs_for_extra(None))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2627, in reqs_for_extra
    if req.marker_fn(override={'extra':extra}):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/_markerlib/markers.py", line 113, in marker_fn
    return eval(compiled_marker, environment)
  File "<environment marker>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'platform_system' is not defined

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

What does it mean and what can i do to make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not really `electrum`, but I faced the same issue and solved it by following a bit different approach:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-bitcoin-core-wallet-ubuntu-16-04-16-10